# Code signing "Bolts.framework" failed

Tags: ios, app-store

I archive my application and now want upload to app store when I validate it or upload this error come to me:

> Code signing "Bolts.framework" failed.

[image]

Any suggestion for these problem?

Comment: what information you got in logs?

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I am also getting this issue. Please help.

Comment: Try to restart your device then change the kaychain password and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
For Me, I Close all programs and restart the device then I change the keychain password and try again and it's working fine.